# How to fix the following so that it can only return the value that does not repeat in the array?

Tags: java

I have a sorted array of ints with some of it's values repeating, but I would like to return the value which does not repeat. For example, I have this:

```
Integer[] arr = {-32735, -32735, -32700, -32645, -32645, -32560, -32560};
```

which should return the value -32700. But, its giving me -32560 as a result.

What could be wrong with my approach?

This is my code:

```
    Integer[] arr = {-32735, -32735, -32700, -32645, -32645, -32560, -32560};
    int n = arr.length;
    //to store repeating element
    int[] temp = new int[1];

    //if only one element return it
    if(arr.length==1)
    {
        System.out.println(arr[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        for(int j=1; j<n-1; j++)
        {   //compare current element with it's previous and subsequent
            if((arr[j-1]!=arr[j]) && (arr[j]!=arr[j+1]))
            {
                temp[0] = arr[j];
            }

        }
    System.out.println(temp[0]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are comparing Integer objects instance equality and not the values. Just taking your code gives me warnings in my IDE for the comparisons you are using. If you want to do the comparisons with primitive values the easiest change to do is to change the declaration of your array into

```
int[] arr = {-32735, -32735, -32700, -32645, -32645, -32560, -32560};
```

Doing that will produce the intended result `-32700`

An alternate solution if you want to keep your array with Integer objects is to do as Michael Michailidis suggested and use equals in the comparisons instead.

Answer (score 1):

The reason -32560 is being returned is because you are trying to compare number objects (`Integer`) using the `!=` operator, which will almost always return true (hence the final value is returned) because all the Integers within the array are technically not equal to each other (their object refs will be different).

You can fix this by changing the line:

```
if((arr[j-1]!=arr[j]) && (arr[j]!=arr[j+1]))
```

to

```
if(!(arr[j-1].equals(arr[j])) && !(arr[j].equals(arr[j+1])))
```

**OR** you can change the array to be an array of primitive `int`s instead of the number class `Integer`

```
Integer[] arr = {-32735, -32735, -32700, -32645, -32645, -32560, -32560};
```

to

```
int[] arr = {-32735, -32735, -32700, -32645, -32645, -32560, -32560};
```

Either method will work - hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Operators are not doing same with type int (x==y) or class Integer (x.equals(y))
to fix use appropriate Integer operators:

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     int[] arr = {-32735, -32735, -32700, -32645, -32645, -32560, -32560};

        for(int j=1; j<arr.length-1; j++)
            if((arr[j-1]!=arr[j]) && (arr[j]!=arr[j+1])) 
                System.out.println("int>"+arr[j]);


    Integer[] I_arr = {-32735, -32735, -32700, -32645, -32645, -32560, -32560};

        for(int j=1; j<I_arr.length-1; j++)
            if((!I_arr[j-1].equals(I_arr[j])) && (!I_arr[j].equals(I_arr[j+1]))) 
                System.out.println("Interger>"+I_arr[j]);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
      Integer[] arr = {-32735, -32735, -32700, -32645, -32645, -32560, -32560};
        int n = arr.length;
        //to store repeating element
        int[] temp = new int[1];

        //if only one element return it
        if (arr.length == 1) {
            System.out.println(arr[0]);
        } else {
            for (int j = 1; j < n - 1; j++) {   //compare current element with it's previous and subsequent
                if ((!arr[j - 1].equals(arr[j])) && (!arr[j].equals(arr[j + 1]))) {
                    temp[0] = arr[j];
                }

            }
            System.out.println(temp[0]);
        }
```

Your code now is working. The problem was the object comparison you had. `Integer` is an object (wrapper) while `int` is a primitive. == and =! works well on primitives but not on objects

Comment: I'm pretty sure a number is considered "repeating" even if its neighbors aren't the same.  `Integer[] arr = {1, 2, 1, 2}` would return 1.

Comment: @Neil The code is not my own. I revised the questions code. The questions is talking about a "sorted" array. Thus the solution comes for "sorted" arrays.

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish the same task of finding the unique element recursively?

Comment: @elnamy Yes you can. But for sorted array only as you will need a function that takes the previous, the counter and the array in. But will not be faster and only stress the memory as it will load unfinished functions till recursion finds the unique and return. You have a specific reason to change this code? There may be an other approach to help your case

Comment: Just for curiosity how could it be done recursively?.. if you could present it in pseudocode that would be fine.

Comment: @elnamy something like that. https://pastebin.com/SZ7pieiM . It has window for improvements but the core problem is a recursion must have something to return. if the array has no duplicates this will return -1 which is valid value for the array to have. ( meaning it has nothing to return, throwing exception is not a good practice). It propably has more flaws as i did it on the fly. But I think you get the point

Answer (score 0):

Use int instead of Integer in below line.

```
Integer[] arr = {-32735, -32735, -32700, -32645, -32645, -32560, -32560};
```

You are creating Integer objects in the Array. In order to compare objects, equals() method is required...